# Passing a variable containing a comma separated list of values in a meta-query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, variables

My objective here is to collect a series of values from a custom repeater field into a comma separated list so they can be used in a meta query. The first part of this is operational, and I think generating what I need:

```
$artists_ids = array(); // Initialize an empty array to store artist IDs
if(have_rows('release_artist')): 
    while(have_rows('release_artist')): the_row();
        $artist = get_sub_field('artist');
        $artists_ids[] = $artist->ID; // Add artist ID to array
        $artists_string = implode("', '", $artists_ids); // Make a comma separated list
        $artists_string_value = "'".$artists_string."'"; // Add initial/final ' to list
    endwhile; 
else: endif;
```

When I run this, `print_r($artists_string_value);` is returning a list of IDs, formatted as follows:

`'1302', '1329'`

I have a meta query that is working as intended when this exact data is manually input as value, but when I pass the same info as a variable, the query returns no results:

```
'post_type'         => 'releases',
'posts_per_page'    => 6,
'order'             => 'DESC',
'post__not_in'      => array( $post->ID ),
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'           => 'release_artist_$_artist',
        'value'         => array( '1302', '1329' ),          // this works
        // 'value'      => array( $artists_string_value ),   // this does not
        'compare'       => 'IN'
    )
),
```

I am struggling to understand why one version of this works but not the other. Does the variable change the way the information is formatted in a way that `print_r();` won't show me, or is it not possible to use a variable in a meta query like this for some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress meta queries, when using the 'compare' => 'IN' comparison, the value should be an array, not a string. When you manually input array( '1302', '1329' ), it works because it's correctly formatted as an array. However, when using $artists_string_value, it's treated as a single string, not an array of values.

You should modify your code to use the $artists_ids array directly in your meta query instead of converting it into a string. Your meta query should look like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key'     => 'release_artist_$_artist',
    'value'   => $artists_ids, // Use the array directly
    'compare' => 'IN'
  )
),

$artists_ids = array(); // Initialize an empty array to store artist IDs
if (have_rows('release_artist')): 
  while (have_rows('release_artist')): the_row();
    $artist = get_sub_field('artist');
    if ($artist) {
        $artists_ids[] = $artist->ID; // Add artist ID to array
    }
  endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: This works perfectly Lovin, thank you. I really thought I had tried this at the start, must have got something wrong somewhere. Appreciate the help.